# Bool: Direct assignment or conditional?

Tags: c, coding-style

What's the "proper" C way of assigning a bool?

```
#include <stdbool.h>
```

a)

```
bool a_state = (a_value > 0);
```

b)

```
bool a_state;
if (a_value > 0) {a_state = true;} else {a_state = false;}
```

c)

```
bool a_state = false;
if (a_value > 0) {a_state = true;}
```

d)

```
bool a_state = (a_value > 0)? true: false;
```

Which one is clearer and more "C-like"?

EDIT: added 2 more; added bool header `#include`

Comment: I vote choice a for conciseness.

Comment: The 1st is clear and short. That's all it needs.

Comment: None, as there is no `bool` in Standard C btw ... ;-)

Comment: Initialisation on definition is preferred as less error-prone.

Comment: @alk; There is `bool` type in standard C.

Comment: Yes, but it's not called `bool`. @haccks

Comment: Okokok, in `stdbool.h`  there is a macro `bool` expanding to the C (>=C99) type `_Bool`. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Its a matter of choice. You can go with either. First snippet is equivalent to second.

Comment: I know they are all equivalent. I am asking which one is clearer, please.

Comment: I know what you are asking. I said go with either.